# Getting "NameError: name 'self' is not defined" while executing the following program

Tags: python-3.x, python-class

```
class inputoutstring(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.s = ""

class getstring(self):
    self.s = input("Enter the string for printing")

class printstring(self):
    print(self.s.upper())

str_obj = inputoutstring()

str_obj.getstring()

str_obj.printstring()
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining class instead of function, replace the second, third and last "class" by "def" and indent the code. I think you will be set !

Like the following code:

```
class inputoutstring(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.s = ""

    def getstring(self):
        self.s = input("Enter the string for printing")

    def printstring(self):
        print(self.s.upper())

str_obj = inputoutstring()

str_obj.getstring()

str_obj.printstring()
```

Answer (score 0):

The class `class getstring(self):` cant be invoked like `str_obj.getstring()` because it refers to a function call.I think you misplaced the functions with class.
You only need to define the `getstring()` `printstring()` as functions and include them in the scope of `inputoutstring class` such as below:

```
class inputoutstring(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.s = ""

    def getstring(self):
        self.s = input("Enter the string for printing: ")

    def printstring(self):
        print(self.s.upper())

str_obj = inputoutstring()

str_obj.getstring()

str_obj.printstring()
```

output:

```
Enter the string for printing hello
HELLO
```

Hope this helps!